# Clarification on Measure Theory

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

My text book says that the Lebesgue measure on Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ is not complete . I am looking for such a Borel set which has measure $0$ but its subset is not a Borel set. Such set must exist or else it will be a complete measure space. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The Cantor set will do the job.

Comment: There are only continuum many Borel sets.

Comment: @PhoemueX Presumably the OP also wants to know about a non-Borel *subset* . . .

Comment: For future reference, you should make your titles specific problem or a brief summary of your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed, such sets will exist. You don't even need measure theory to show this!

- It's not too hard to show (*caveat: you do need a small amount of the axiom of choice here, namely that the union of countably many countable sets is countable; surprisingly, this is **not** provable in ZF alone*) that there are continuum-many Borel sets of reals, while there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$-many subsets of any set of reals of size continuum. Combining these facts, a counting argument shows that there must be some non-Borel subset of the Cantor set, which is Borel (indeed, closed) and has measure zero.
- This doesn't produce a specific example, unfortunately. Explicit examples *are* possible, but they're somewhat harder to describe. My personal favorite is as follows. There is a natural way to represent an element of the Cantor set as an infinite sequence of 0s and 1s (via ternary expansion), and there is a natural way to represent a binary relation $R$ on $\mathbb{N}$ as an infinite sequence of 0s and 1s (a 1 in the $2^m3^n$th bit exactly when $R(m, n)$ holds, and zeroes elsewhere). Thus, letting $W$ be the set of points in the Cantor set which are the codes of **well-ordered relations** on $\mathbb{N}$, we get a reasonably definable set of reals. Perhaps surprisingly, this set is not Borel!

Comment: Since I mention choice in my answer, let me just point out that ZF proves that the set $W$ has no Borel *code*; however, "every Borel set has a Borel code" is itself a very weak form of the axiom of choice, so in ZF it's possible for $W$ to be Borel, in the sense of being an element of the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets (indeed, it's possible in ZF for every set of reals to be $\Sigma^0_3$ - this will happen if $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of countable sets). However, it's worth pointing out that measure theory as a whole basically collapses without this much choice.